# Unable to delete a record using Delete verb of REST api

Tags: rest, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to delete a record from a dropdownlist on button click. When I inspect, I see these errors:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405
>   (Method Not Allowed) dropdown.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://toyauction.azurewebsites.net/api/toys/19. Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

I know that the function is picking up the correct id of the toy that needs to be deleted.

My Code:

```
$('#deleteToy').click(function(){
               $.ajax({
                    url: baseURI + "toys/" + toydropdown.val(),
                    method: "DELETE",
                   dataType: "json",
                    data: {},

                       error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       alert("An error occurred!!");
               }

                }).done(function (result) {
                    // display a message that the toy is deleted
                    $('<p></p>').html(result.Name + ' toy deleted!').prependTo('section#toy');
                    // TODO: refresh the toy dropdown list
                    getToys(toysdropdown);

                });

                });
```

Comment: 405 means DELETE method is not allowed on this endpoint, at-least not with credentials you are logged in with. Are you sure DELETE method is allowed for this specific endpoint? And you have privileges for this method?

Comment: When I try to delete from the same table and database using POSTMAN, I am able to delete the items.

Comment: In that case you simply need to compare your Postman req with this one. Can you share the Postman req?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Could you try "type" instead of "method".

Comment: This is the generated code in Postman:  DELETE /api/toys/43 HTTP/1.1
Host: toyauction.azurewebsites.net
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: af21aeb1-dd6e-0953-def9-c52f1cb7ae13

{
    Name: "Panda",
    NumberLegs: "4",
    ColorID: 3,
    OwnerID: 8
}

Comment: I tried using type instead of method, but it is not working.

Comment: Perhaps, you are not passing the access token with the *DELETE* call?

Comment: Can you  tell me exactly what I have to include?